# неверно определяется позиция скролла React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть два компонента(они же две странице в роуте, главная страница со списком элементов и страница подробного описания). при прокрутке элементы подгружаются по 20шт. Хочу сделать, чтобы при переходе на страницу с подробным описанием элемента списка, сохранять позицию скролла. Чтобы при возвращении назад, мы были рядом с тем элементом по которому кликнули.
Сделал стейт:

```
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState({
    scrollX: 0,
    scrollY: 0,
  });
  console.log("State scrollPosition: ", scrollPosition);
```

Сделал обработчик клика:

```
const getCurrentScrollPosition = (e) => {
    //e.preventDefault();
    let cordsAfterClick = {};
    let cords = ["scrollX", "scrollY"];
    cords.forEach((cord) => {
      cordsAfterClick[cord] = window[cord];
    });
    console.log("Obj with cords: ", cordsAfterClick);
    localStorage.setItem("scrollCord", JSON.stringify(cordsAfterClick));
  };
```

Так же сохраняю данные в локальное хранилище. Далее в useEffect я обновляю стейт и устанавливаю позицию скролла:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setScrollPosition(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("scrollCord")));
    window.scrollBy(scrollPosition.scrollX, scrollPosition.scrollY);
  }, [scrollPosition.scrollX, scrollPosition.scrollY]);
```

Но вот проблема в том, что позиция window.scrollBy() не совпадает. Приведу скрины:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: LocalStorage]

В чем моя ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста.
ps: И может вообще есть решение лучше? а то чувствую, что наворотил делов))

Comment: Попробуй перед установкой позиции, принудительно устанавливать 'focus' на элемент с прокруткой

Comment: Благодарю за коммент. я нашел проблему. если установку скролла поставить с маленькой задержкой, то все работает корректно: `setTimeout(() => {window.scrollTo(scrollPosition.scrollX, scrollPosition.scrollY)}, 500);` . получается, то скролл уже летит вниз к координатам, еще до того как успевают  отрендериться все элементы списка. но скорее всего использовать тайм-аут - это  "не очень" решение. и вообще я думал, что используя `useEffect`, не столкнусь с такой проблемой)